# Escaping a colon from the azureDB hostname in a connection url string using python

Tags: python, azure-sql-database

Hi I am curently trying to connect to an azure database through a python module.

When I format a connection string like this

```
connection_string = f"{sql_config['driver']}://{username}:{password}@{sql_config['host']}:{sql_config['port']}/{sql_config['database']}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;"
connection = create_engine(connection_string)
```

When the host has a colon in the name such as `"tcp:servername.database.windows.net"`, it will return `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'servername.database.windows.net:1433'` as it thinks the colon separates the host and the port. Is there anyway to escape the character? I have tried using `{}`, `''`, `""` to escape the colon to no success.

I would like to keep the connection string as an URL.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that makes TCP the protocol, and possibly 'servername.database.windows.net' the host. Therefore I think you should split it by ':', then reformat it into 'tcp:username:password@servername.database.windows.net:port'. However, I'm not entirely sure how a TCP URI looks like, this just my guess.

Comment: Thanks I will try that, but from what I see on the AzureDB ODBC configuration. Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;

I'm assuming tcp: is part of the database hostname?

Comment: As per the [RFC on hostnames](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.2), I'm fairly sure it can't be a hostname, and therefore must be the protocol.

Comment: Unfortunately with the solution proposed, it ends up being parsed as the username. The same problem happens as the colon is interpreted as a split